# Which columns to index with LEFT JOIN and GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, index, performance, optimization, query-performance

So i have a complicated MySQL search query, and I wonder which columns I need to index to speed up searching:

```
        SELECT wpp.ID, post_title, wp_terms.name AS category, wp_terms.slug AS slug, supplier_company, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(wp_terms.slug SEPARATOR ', ') AS allslug,
        GROUP_CONCAT(wp_terms.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS allcatname
        FROM wp_posts AS wpp
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wpp.ID = object_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_teleapo_supplier AS s ON wpp.post_author = s.ID

        WHERE post_type = 'post' 
        GROUP BY wpp.ID
```

1) How to speed up the group_concat?
2) Should I index the column for `ON` at my `LEFT JOIN`s? Like: `wpp.ID` and `object_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create indices for all the fields you have used to bind tables or to restrict results:

```
wpp.ID 
object_id 
term_taxonomy_id 
wp_terms.term_id
wpp.post_author 
s.ID
post_type
```

Some of fields are already indexed as primary keys so do not duplicate indices, that can impact RAM consumption as well as performance.

First you have to do now - is to launch your query with `EXPLAIN` prefix and show the result.

N.B.

Always use aliases for joined tables, like third one in your code. Always specify explicitly table you refer to, like `wp_terms.term_id` or `s.id`.

Comment: Cheers! Why always use aliases?

Comment: Just because that allow to avoid ambiguity before it occur. I'm used to set single-letter alias for every table used in the query. Also, my IDE for `mysql` provide code-completion and work pretty well with aliases. So when I've enter `w.` IDE shows popup with possible variants.